# How to move a label on a dropdown form from the top to the side

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a simple dropdown form with choices. There is a label on the top of the dropdown to discern what the dropdown is referring to.

I would like to know if there is a way to move the title from above the dropdown, to the left of the drop down.

```
function DropdownForm(props: Props) {
    const { choices, label, onChange } = props;
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control as="select" onChange={onChange}>
                    {choices.map((choice) => (
                        <option key={choice}>{choice}</option>
                    ))}
                </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

[I want to move the "Test" label to the left of the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juIL8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function DropdownForm(props: Props) {
    const { choices, label, onChange } = props;
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlaintextEmail">
                <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    {label}
                </Form.Label>
                <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control as="select" onChange={onChange}>
                        {choices.map((choice) => (
                            <option key={choice}>{choice}</option>
                        ))}
                    </Form.Control>
                </Col>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    );
}
```